# How to distribute layers along a path?

Tags: after-effects

Is it possible to "distribute" layers along a path?

I want to create lights along a text stroke path. I could of course align like 200 light layer elements on the path of the text letters manually. But maybe there are better ways to somehow automate this? Like stroking or filling the text letters/mask with the contents of another layer?